# malloc memory allocation scheme in C

Tags: c, malloc

I was experimenting with malloc in C and I have observed that malloc is wasting some space after some memory has been allocated. Below is the piece of code I used to test malloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* a;
    char* b;
    a=malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    b=malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    memset(a,9,2);
    memset(b,9,2);
    return 0;
}
```

In the right-middle of the following picture(open the image in a new tab for clarity) you can see the memory contents;0x804b008 is the address pointed by variable 'a' and 0x804b018 is the memory pointed by variable 'b'. what is happening to memory between from 0x804b00a 0x804b017? The thing is even if I try to allocate `3*sizeof(char)` instead of `2*sizeof(char)` bytes of memory the memory layout is the same! So, is there something I am missing?

[image: gdb interface]

Comment: In addition to the answer below it’s worth pointing out that sizeof(char)=1 by definition, so there is no point multiplying by it.

Comment: @richardkettlewell that's right .. but I made it a habit to use it any way for the sake of readability

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`malloc()` is allowed to waste as much space as it wants to - the standard doesn't specify *anything* about the implementation.  The only guarantee you have is about alignment (**§7.20.3 Memory management functions**):

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

Your implementation appears to return you minimum-8-byte-aligned pointers.

Comment: what is the 7.20.3 you are referring to? Is it a chapter of some C standards book? if so, could you point me to that book.

Comment: @vamsi, yes it's from the C spec.  PDF link: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Memory Alignment! It's good for perfomance in x86 and mandatory in some architectures like ARM.

> Most CPUs require that objects and variables reside at particular offsets in the system's memory. For example, 32-bit processors require a 4-byte integer to reside at a memory address that is evenly divisible by 4. This requirement is called "memory alignment". Thus, a 4-byte int can be located at memory address 0x2000 or 0x2004, but not at 0x2001. On most Unix systems, an attempt to use misaligned data results in a bus error, which terminates the program altogether. On Intel processors, the use of misaligned data is supported but at a substantial performance penalty. Therefore, most compilers automatically align data variables according to their type and the particular processor being used. This is why the size that structs and classes occupy is often larger than the sum of their members'

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13265

Answer (score 1):

The heap is handled by the implementation, not necessarily as you expect.  The Standard explicitly doesn't guarantee anything about order or contiguity.  There are two main things that cause more heap space to be used than you asked for.

First, allocated memory has to be aligned so that it's suitable for use by any sort of object.  Typically, computers expect primitive data objects of N bytes to be allocated at a multiple of N, so the odds are you can't get `malloc()` to return a value that isn't a multiple of 8.

Second, the heap needs to be managed, so that `free()` allows reuse of the memory.  This means that the heap manager needs to keep track of allocated and unallocated blocks, and their sizes.  One practice is to stick some information in memory just before each block, so the manager can know what size block to free and where blocks are that might be reused.  If that's what your system does, there will be more memory used between allocated blocks, and given alignment restrictions at 8 bytes it's likely you can't get allocations of less than 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern `malloc()` implementations allocate in powers of two and have a minimum allocation size, to reduce fragmentation since oddball sizes could generally only be reused when enough contiguous allocations are `free()`d to make larger blocks.  (It also speeds up coalescing contiguous allocations in general, IIRC.)  Also keep in mind the block overhead; to get the block size you need to add some amount (8 in GNU `malloc()`, IIRC) for internal management uses.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` is only guaranteed to return you a block of memory that's at least as big as the size you give it.  However, processors are generally more efficient when they're operating on blocks of memory that start at multiples of, say, 8 bytes in memory.  Look up *word size* for more information on this.