# Pointer confusion in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * a);
    int *g = malloc(sizeof(int) * a);
    p += 8;
    printf("%p\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", g);
    
}
```

I have run this program several times, and every time the values of p and g printed at the end are the same. I'm not quite sure why this is happening - couldn't malloc theoretically pick anywhere in memory to have p and g point to? Why does p + 8 always equal g? Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You go to a bakery and ask for a donut. The clerk gets it for you. You ask for another. The clerk gets one that was next to the first one. You do this every day, and, every day, the clerk gives you two donuts that were next to each other. Even on days when there are more or fewer donuts on the shelf, the clerk gets the next two for you. Why are you surprised?

Comment: On modern systems with [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), every time you run the program, it starts with the exact same (virtual) memory setup, so there's no reason why `malloc` can't behave exactly the same way. On the other hand, `malloc` might deliberately behave differently for security reasons, e.g. [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: @EricPostpischil That seems like a poor analogy, since he's probably thinking "Every day I go to the bakery, and the donuts are in different positions because other people have come and gone before me

Comment: Actually, Barmar, this is equivalent to him always being the very first customer each day :)

Comment: Let's say p is given the value of 0x1000. Then, this is &p[0]. Likewise, &p[1] = 0x1004, &p[2] = 0x1008, &p[3] = 0x100c. Overall, the array p covers memory addresses 0x1000 to 0x100f. But, isn't p + 8 equal to &p[8]? What happens to the memory where p[4 to 7] would normally be stored?

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(int*)`?

Comment: Sizeof(int) is 4, I know. And sizeof(int*) is 8 here. So, p + 8 = p + (8 * sizeof(int)) = p + 32 bytes. But, if g is the immediate next memory address, shouldn't it be p + 4 = p + 16 bytes ? Since the array p only takes up addresses p + 0 .... p + 15.

Comment: @Barmar in fact he is always the first customer of the day in this case, each run of this app creates a brand new donut store

Comment: @EdricAntoine Some `malloc` implementations store bookkeeping information in the bytes *before* the returned pointer. That information may be used by `free` when releasing the memory. For example, if `malloc` returns 0x1000, then there may be 16 bytes of bookkeeping information starting at address 0x0ff0. On the other hand, `malloc` may just be enforcing a minimum allocation size of 32 bytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does malloc allocate a different number of bytes than requested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430163/why-does-malloc-allocate-a-different-number-of-bytes-than-requested)

Comment: ...or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6389120/2505965), or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13064850/2505965), or even [this!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1518711/2505965)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Then there was that trip to the bakery, as a kid, to purchase two doughnuts. I was given the last one on the shelf, then waited 2 minutes while the worker fetched another tray (freshly made) from the back of the shop... Had to remember which-was-which so as to give the "older" (stale) one to my sister... An analogy must be carefully crafted (like a good doughnut.)

Answer (score 2):

> I have run this program several times, and every time the values of p and g printed at the end are the same

This is because of how your memory happened to be allocated.

The first `malloc` allocates memory for 4 integers. Let's say they're 4 bytes each so 16 bytes.

```
0              1              2              3 
0123456789abdef0123456789abdef0123456789abdef0123456789abdef
^--------------
p
```

The second `malloc` allocates memory for another 4 integers. This memory could be allocated in any free slot, but it just so happens to be like so.

```
0              1              2              3 
0123456789abdef0123456789abdef0123456789abdef0123456789abdef
^--------------               ^--------------
p                             g
```

If you add 8 to `p`, that moves it by the size of 8 integers, 32 bytes, which is `g`.

What's in the memory in the gap? Who knows. Memory can be allocated however `malloc` thinks appropriate.

---

However, there is ***no guarantee*** the memory will be allocated this way. On my system `p += 4` works meaning there's no gap.

Answer (score 1):

### It is how malloc() works

`malloc` reserves memory on a **heap** in so called **chunks** which can be variable size (fixed size  header + variable size data).
Smallest amount of data that can be allocated is 16 bytes.

> Minimum allocated size: 4-byte ptrs:  16 bytes    (including overhead)
> 8-byte ptrs:  32 bytes    (including overhead)

Although you allocated `4 * sizeof(int)` of data, `malloc` use "chunks" which have additional metadata for bookkeeping, needed when you `free` memory.

> Minimum overhead per allocated chunk:   4 or  8 bytes (if 4byte sizes)
> 8 or 16 bytes (if 8byte sizes)
> Each malloced chunk has a hidden word of overhead holding size
> and status information, and additional cross-check word

`malloc` wants to avoid segmentation of free memory.
So it is logical for `malloc` to place 2 chunks next to each other to prevent memory leaks and it makes sense to put them together since it is most efficient way.

If we assume `int` size is 4 bytes, you have to increment first pointer by  `8 * sizeof(int)` or 32 bytes to point at the next allocated data:

```
p + header size(16 bytes) + data size(16 bytes) = b
p + 32 = b
```

Here is an image of 2 adjacent `malloc` chunks:

[image]

Comment: "*It is how malloc() works*" It is how *some* mallocs work. It's a very good explanation, but we need to be clear you're describing a particular implementation of malloc.

Comment: I admit I am somewhat familiar only with glibc malloc and dlmalloc. but yes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does p + 8 always equal g?

is the wrong question. They are always equal *so far*, on your specific system, in your specific program.

Why shouldn't they be the same? Unless you have a reason to believe this is impossible or explicitly prohibited, why should it be surprising?

> couldn't malloc theoretically pick anywhere in memory to have p and g point to?

Well, anywhere available to the free store. But that doesn't mean it's randomised - that would just be extra work for no benefit.